# cypress: css selector to select an anchor by text

Tags: css, css-selectors, cypress

I'm starting to play with [cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) and I need to select a link like this:

```
<table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" border="0" class="ToolBarBkg">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="ContentLeftLinks" align="right" width="98%" height="40" nowrap>
        &nbsp;
        <a href="javascript:FireEvent('Agregar')" style="COLOR: black; font-weight: normal" tabindex="-1">
          <IMG src="/metassc/images/toolbar/AltaOn.gif" align="absmiddle" border=0> Alta
        </a>
        &nbsp;

        <a href="javascript:FireEvent('Eliminar')" style="COLOR: black; font-weight: normal" tabindex="-1">

          <IMG src="/metassc/images/toolbar/BajaOn.gif" align="absmiddle" border=0> Baja
        </a>
```

Following [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) I already tried with these:

```
cy.contains('a[href~=Agregar]')
cy.contains('a[href*="Agregar"]')
cy.contains('a:contains("^Agregar$") ')
cy.contains('a:contains("^Alta$") ')
```

But none of them seems to work. Any idea?

Answer (score 6):

`cy.contains()` can also take two arguments:

```js
cy.contains('a', 'Alta')
```

This gets the first `a` element containing the text `Alta`

Answer (score 1):

There is this popular library > [cypress-testing-library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-testing-library)

This makes it really easy to get selectors by **text, title, value, alt text** etc.

For your issue you can simply use **getByText** method from this library:
`cy.getByText('Agregar').click()`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, had to use `cy.get` instead of contains

```
cy.get('a[href*="Agregar"]')
  .click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is, you could probably drill down till `<a>` tag via `parent()` and `find()` method in cypress;

```
cy.get('a:contains("Agregar")').parents('.ToolBarBkg').find('tbody').find('tr').find('td').find('a').contains("Agregar").click();
```